# How do I change system time in android

Tags: android

I want to change or set the system time in android by my application,how can I do that?
instead of the way Intent

Comment: see this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11457698/519718

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update the android time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457502/how-to-update-the-android-time)