# How to update the android time

Tags: android, time

I am using android TAB for some app development . 
in my application I get UTC time from the other application(other device provides to my application via TCP socket ) . Once I receive this I need to update the time with receive time . Is there any apis to change the system time ..?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean setCurrentTimeMillis (long millis)
```

Sets the current wall time, in milliseconds. **Requires the calling process to have appropriate permissions.** [although Only system process can change the time]

**User apps cannot set the time. Only the system processes can. This is
for
security, but also because I think it won't have much effect-- the time does reset from
the radio via network time.**

[reference link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/855ae4fe695d3e70?pli=1)

Comment: Thanks for calling me on that. I did a quick search and posted something unhelpful.

Comment: can root permission help with this?